# XCode LLDB command po can't output info

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I set a breakpoint to see the value of `string` in console .But the `po`command doesn't work. A little earlier it was fine, but now left is OK and right is going wrong – why and how? Here is the pic:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that on the left is a previous run and the right is the current run, or are they both the same screenshot?

Comment: what happens if you say p string instead of po string?

Comment: @xiaofei xu were you able to solve that ?